# Set column value of a view based on which table I'm selecting from

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a view from 2 tables. I need to create a brand new column in the view; this column must be set to 0 when I'm selecting from the first table, 1 from the second one:

```
Table A:
+---------+---------+
|column A |column B |
+---------+---------+
|  Boston |   USA   |
+---------+---------+
| Chicago |   USA   |
+---------+---------+
|Las Vegas|   USA   |
+---------+---------+

Table B:
+---------+---------+
|column A |column B |
+---------+---------+
|  Paris  |  Europe |
+---------+---------+
|  Madrid |  Europe |
+---------+---------+
|  London |  Europe |
+---------+---------+

Resulting View:
+---------+---------+---------+
|column A |column B | column C|
+---------+---------+---------+
|  Boston |   USA   |    0    |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Chicago |   USA   |    0    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|Las Vegas|   USA   |    0    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  Paris  |  Europe |    1    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  Madrid |  Europe |    1    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  London |  Europe |    1    |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: what is the query you are using? If you are using union it is pretty straightforward to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a union with a computed column:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, 0 AS columnC FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT columnA, columnB, 1 FROM TableB
ORDER BY columnC;
```

Comment: you were faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columnA, colunmB, 0 as columnC from tableA
UNION
SELECT columnA, colunmB, 1 as columnC from tableB,
```

it looks like you are using UNION to create the view. Then just add the dummy field in each sql